# R number of times an expression evaluates in a for loop

Tags: r

How many times the list.files('dir_path') evaluates in a for loop? Is it equal to the number of files present in a directory? How do we verify it?

```
for (infile in list.files('dir_path')){
     #doSomething()
}
```

Should I have to create a variable first and then pass it in for loop?

For example:

```
selected_files = list.files('dir_path')

for (infile in selected_files){
         #doSomething()
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Just to add some value, you can use `pryr::show_c_source(.Primitive("for"))` in order to inspect `for` source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`list.files` will only be evaluated once when you use it in a for-loop like the one you propose. The easiest way to test this is to wrap the call to `list.files` in another function call, like this:

```
f <- function() { print("Calling f"); list.files() }
```

and use that in the for-loop:

```
for (infile in f())
{
    print(infile)
}
```